# Best way to get the PID of a command that is built and run through array in a bash script?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, scripting

I am running a command this way:

```
# Run 
if [[ $1 == A ]]; then
    CMDD=(sudo ${path}/my_exe -O ${fileA})
elif [[ $1 == B ]]; then
    CMDD=(sudo ${path}/my_exe -O ${fileB})
fi
"${CMDD[@]}" & pid=$!
```

but when I echo the pid in the same script:

```
echo "pid: " $pid
```

> 2345

I do not get the pid of the process that I just run, which btw has 2 pids because I run it with sudo:

> 2346
> 2347

therefore if I run this command in the script, it does not kill the processes I wanted to kill:

```
sudo kill -9 $pid
```

I did some research but I couldn't find yet the best way to kill the processes I created in a clean manner. What would you suggest?

Example script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Test
CMDD=(sudo sleep $1 )
"${CMDD[@]}" & pid=$!
echo "pid: " $pid
exit
```

Comment: Seems to work for me, `$!` gives the PID of the sudo process. I don't think the array has anything to do it, btw. What are the two processes that you have that end up running? The ones whose PIDs here were 2346 and 7. Can you show a sample run of how exactly you tested that. What's your sudo version?

Comment: I can't reproduce here. Do you get different pids in `cmd=(sudo sleep 2); "${cmd[@]}" & sleep 1; echo "$!"; ps -opid,ppid,args -HC sudo; wait` or `sudo sleep 2 & sleep 1; echo "$!"; ps -opid,ppid,args -HC sudo; wait`

Comment: thanks guys for your inputs, @ilkkachu I just added an example script at the end of my question. When I run it (./test_pid.sh 15), it printed `pid:  304862`, however if I do _pgrep sleep_ I get 304863. Therefore I could not use `sudo kill -9 $pid` to kill the process in my script.

Comment: Can't reproduce. Add `set -x` at the beginning, it may help to debug. Is `$pid` just empty?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas thanks for your comment! See my comment above.

Comment: @dimich thanks for your comment! I just added more info in my comment above.

Comment: Sudo version 1.8.31

Comment: @guidocasati you got pid of `sudo` as last executed background command. Bash can't know if background command spawns child processes.

Comment: SIGKILL can't be caught, so sudo can't relay it to child process. See `Signal handling` in sudo manual. Try to send SIGTERM instead of SIGKILL.

Comment: @dimich thanks. I see in the manual that _As a general rule, SIGTSTP should be used instead of SIGSTOP when you wish to suspend a command being run by sudo_ - I tried that in my script with kill -TSTP but it does not kill the process as intended yet. I need to learn more about this topic.

Comment: @guidocasati Why SIGSTOP/SIGTSTP? They are for stopping process, not terminating. If you want to terminate process, run `sudo kill -SIGTERM $pid` (or `kill -15 ...` instead of `-9`). Of course your `my_exe` shouldn't block or mask SIGTERM in this case.